# Impractical inference time on Tensorflow model with large embedding vocabulary

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recommendation-engine, tensorflow-serving, latency

I have noticed a phenomenon whereby there is a linear relationship between embedding vocabulary size in a Tensorflow model and its inference time.

This in itself I do not find surprising.  However the steepness of the relationship I have found to be surprising and impractical.

I have created a simple sequential model with a vocabulary size of 10 million and running a single inference through the model takes 82 seconds on my M1 Pro laptop.

I have created a minimal script that reproduces the effect:

```
import time
import uuid
import tensorflow as tf

def create_vocab(vocab_size):
    return [str(uuid.uuid4()) for i in range(vocab_size)]

def run(vocab_size):
    vocabulary = create_vocab(vocab_size)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                        tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
                            vocabulary=vocabulary,
                            mask_token=None),
                        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
                            vocab_size + 1,
                            24)
                    ])

    t1 = time.time()
    model.predict([vocabulary[4]])
    t2 = time.time()
    inference_time = t2-t1
    print(f"Vocab size: {vocab_size} / Inference time: {inference_time}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for vocab_size in [1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]:
        run(vocab_size)
```

The results I get are:
Vocab_Size  Inference time
1000            0.041
10000           0.106
100000          0.718
1000000         7.351
10000000    82.48

I can only assume that this is expected behaviour and I am using the wrong pattern. However, my question then is, how might I build a performant online model that uses high volumes of embeddings? The use case I have here is users in a recommender system where I would like to perform realtime inference on a model containing at least 10m user embeddings in <200ms. There must be many online models that achieve this. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE, SOLVED: It was solved by removing the string lookup from the model as it appears this component is particularly inefficient. The alternative approach is to do a string-to-int user mapping and use this as input instead. With this approach, the 10m vocab variant returns in 200ms.